# determine assosicate service installed certficate on windows server 2003 or which service is using that certficate

Tags: windows, certificate

I have been facing issue to determine the purpose of installed certificate on windows server. Further, Is there any way to determine which service is using any particular certificate. So that before remove that certificate I can determine that potential impacted services.

Please suggest, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Each certificate has been issued for one or more general purposes, you can see this in the `Enchanced Key Usage` field, something like: `Server Authentication`,`Client Authentication` or `Secure Email`.
There is no way to determine what the specific purpose of a certificate on a server is unless your installation process included proper documentation.

There is no direct relation between a certificate and a service or application in the OS. An application or service can access a certificate by its thumbprint or any other public properties or key file. If you have the source code for the service you can find out how it is choosing a particular certificate.

In the future script all installations of certificates and in the script have some comments about the purpose of the certificate as documentation.